# PHP Websockets server stops accepting connections after 256 users

Tags: php, apache, sockets, websocket

I am running a websockets server using https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets/blob/master/websockets.php on an Ubuntu 16 box with PHP7

After 256 users connect to the websocket, it stops taking connections and I can't figure out why. In the client, I get a 1006 error code (connection was closed abnormally (locally) by the browser implementation) and no further information. The websockets request doesn't appear to make it to the websockets server (which normally echos "Client Connected" right after a socket connection is made).

In the connect() function, one of the things I do is echo the count of the number of users, sockets and overall memory usage to the log. This problem occurs whenever the user count hits 256 (at which point the socket count is 257 and memory usage around 4Mb). The fact that it happens at 256 makes me think that a limit is being hit somewhere, but I can't find that limit. If I restart the websockets server, everything works fine again.

From my investigation so far, I have tried and checked:

- ulimit (says it's unlimited)
- MySQL connection limit (was set to default, now is 1000, but that didn't help)
- Increased the PHP memory limit (because why not, just to see)
- SOMAXCONN is set to 128, so I don't think this is the problem, but I would have to recompile PHP to test it. I haven't tried this yet.
- Apache: The message I get when the problem occurs is: `[proxy:error] [pid 16785] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: WS: attempt to connect to 10.0.0.240:9000 (websockets.mydomain.com) failed`, which doesn't tell me much about anything. Apache is running MPM prefork and I have increased the spare servers and MaxRequestWorkers

I am open to any suggestions as to where to look next or how to get more detail out of the "Connection Refused" error log from apache!

Thanks

Comment: Can you dump a socket_last_error() from php when it fails?

Comment: If PHP knew when it was failing I could try, but it doesn't seem to ever hit the code, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Apache that holding you up. Try setting the following in your conf file...

```
MaxClients 512
ServerLimit 512
```

(you must set both)
Of course, you can use whatever numbers work for you. In mpm-prefork, you should be able to go to 20,000 but that really shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I have updated the config and restarted apache and the websockets server, now to wait for the next peak time (tomorrow) to see if it worked :) Thanks!

Comment: @BenHolness You can always throw `ab` (apache benchmark tool) at it and make your own peak. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of `ab` but haven't ever used or researched it. Luckily this issue isn't a huge deal (the system just falls back to ajax when it fails), plus I'm pretty busy, so I'm happy to wait until tomorrow!